# I don't get how to get the value of my EditText in my custom Dialog

Tags: java, android

I have to do a small app for a school project on Android, and I wanted to update my listView through a Fullscreen Dialog but I can't find a way to get the values inside my EditText fields to put add them to my ArrayLists.

Here is the code of my Dialog class:

```
package com.example.memo;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class FullscreenDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText titleEdit;
    private EditText infoEdit;
    private EditText fullEdit;

    private ArrayList<String> titleArray;
    private ArrayList<String> infoArray;
    private ArrayList<Integer> imageArray;
    private ArrayList<String> fullArray;


    private Callback callback;

    public FullscreenDialog(ArrayList<String> titleArray, ArrayList<String> infoArray, ArrayList<String> fullArray, ArrayList<Integer> imageArray){
        this.titleArray = titleArray;
        this.infoArray = infoArray;
        this.fullArray = fullArray;
        this.imageArray = imageArray;
    }

    static FullscreenDialog newInstance(ArrayList<String> titleArray, ArrayList<String> infoArray, ArrayList<String> fullArray, ArrayList<Integer> imageArray) {
        return new FullscreenDialog(titleArray,infoArray,fullArray,imageArray);

    }

    public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullscreenDialogTheme);


    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_dialog, container, false);
        ImageButton close = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_close);
        TextView action = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_action);

        EditText titleEdit = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_title);
        EditText infoEdit = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_info);
        EditText fullEdit = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_full);


        close.setOnClickListener(this);
        action.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {

            case R.id.fullscreen_dialog_close:
                dismiss();
                break;

            case R.id.fullscreen_dialog_action:
                this.titleArray.add(titleEdit.getText().toString());
                this.infoArray.add(infoEdit.getText().toString());
                this.fullArray.add(fullEdit.getText().toString());
                this.imageArray.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
                callback.onActionClick("Memo saved!");
                dismiss();
                break;

        }

    }

    public interface Callback {

        void onActionClick(String name);

    }

}
```

I guess I must have made some mistakes on the way I used findViewById or something, but Android is kind of new for me and I can't seem to find where it's wrong.

titleArray, infoArray and fullArray are the ArrayLists in which is stored my data.

imageArray is my ArrayList for my images IDs.

Comment: Are you passing in the different arrays in your constructor in order to store the values from your `EditText`s? Is there a reason you need to pass arrays in like that, or does it not matter?

Comment: Sorry, but yout question seems somewhat confusing. Can you add any image/mockup to show us the scenario of what you're trying to achieve? I read your code and your question but couldn't figure out what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calling or making use of an instance variable (i.e fullEdit, titleEdit etc) that is not initialised. To correct this initialised them in method onCreateView, so it should look like this

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_dialog, container, false);
        ImageButton close = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_close);
        TextView action = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_action);

        titleEdit = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_title);
        infoEdit = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_info);
        fullEdit = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_full);


        close.setOnClickListener(this);
        action.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }
```

With the above the class instance EditText variables are instantiated and can be use to get the text onClick method

Comment: thank you, it seems to be working now. Stupid rookie mistake. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You define the variables titleEdit, infoEdit and full Edit **globally** in the class but the problem is that you defined them again **locally** in the onCreateView method and you assigned them to the view by using findViewById .
So you have 2 kind of variable now :

- the global ones ( doesn't linked yet )
- the local ones ( linked to the view )

When you try to get the value of the editText you accessed to the global ones that is not linked to the View .

To solve that delete the local ones. you onCreateView should look like this :

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_dialog, container, false);
        ImageButton close = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_close);
        TextView action = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_action);

        titleEdit = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_title);
        infoEdit = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_info);
        fullEdit = view.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_dialog_full);


        close.setOnClickListener(this);
        action.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }
```